# Upgrade to PHP 7.2 version in MacOS

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I have installed php7.2 using homebrew. But when i run `php -v` i still get php7.1. Of which i think it wasn't installed with Homebrew. How can i enable disable 7.1 and enable 7.2.

I have tried this as suggested by the install.

```
To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

Finally, check DirectoryIndex includes index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Also tried, uncommenting this line in */etc/apache2/httpd.conf*

```
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this by **linking** the new installed version.
After installing the new php version(7.2) with homebrew, you have to run
   `brew link php@72 --force`

if your previous version was a installed with homebrew, you have to unlink it also. E.g for php 7.1
   `brew unlink php71`

 *This is for the php CLI(command line), for the Apache PHP you need to edit* `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Answer (score 1):

When you run `php -v`, you get the version of PHP that is executed from the command line, not the version of PHP executed from Apache.

If you run:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -version
```

You will have the version of the PHP installed by Homebrew. To set it as the default PHP interpreter from the command line, your `PATH` environment variable should contain `/usr/local/bin/` before `/usr/bin`.

To check the version of PHP executed within Apache run [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) by browsing the following PHP file:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful information, I have managed to solve this by **linking** the installed(7.2) version. See my answer below